# What is the idiomatic Scala way of breaking collection's `find` method with Failure in case of error?

Tags: scala, collections

```
def findUseById(userId: Long, usersJson: Seq[JsObject]): Try[Option[JsObject]] = {
  usersJson.find { userJson =>
    (userJson \ "id").validate[Long] {
      case Right(uid) => uid == userId
      case Left(error) =>
      // How to break find loop and  "map" it to failure 
      // (like Failure(new SomeException())) ?
    }
  }
}
```

What would be idiomatic way of breaking find loop and mapping it to Failure?

- I want to avoid using exceptions (throwing exception and wrapping it into Try())
- I want to avoid using `return`
- This should be more or less performant (so recursion won't work I believe, neither fold, because it scans the collection to the end).

Comment: You can do an early return using `return` .

Comment: @jrook `return` is kinda not idiomatic way in functional programing

Comment: At least in Scala 2.13 collections, `find` method uses `return` (besides java style `while` loop). I cannot think of anything more performant than instantly returning from a function and continue with the rest of the program.

Comment: A tail-recursive loop implementation should  be possible in this case. But I don't think even that would be more performant than an early return (maybe equally as performant though).

Comment: @jrook Scala's collection implementation itself is not idiomatic, since those functional concepts should be mapped somehow  down to JVM in the end.. they give us api to write idiomatic code.

Comment: @Teimuraz what should happen if the second element matches the id you are searching but the second would have failed to be parsed? - BTW, if you are concerned about performance, do not use `Seq` but a concrete type like List or ArraySeq. Additionally, I am not sure if a **Try** of an **Option** is the best type, maybe just use a custom exception for the value not being found? Finally, I guess the best would be to write a tail-recursive algorithm.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, I thought about similar approach, but the problem is that you first iterate through whole collection even if required element was in the beginning.. kinda overhead.

Comment: What's the expected behavior if you find the value in the third position in the list, but the fifth item doesn't validate? Should it return a success or a validation error?

Comment: Seems you are using [Play-Json](https://github.com/playframework/play-json). If that's the case, please add the tag. Also, Play-Json's `validate` returns JsError and JsSuccess that wrap around found value or error message. Unless you apply `asEither`, you cannot match against `Left` and `Right`. But if you are doing this, then why go back to `Try`?

Comment: @jrook it's not about play-json, but about how to handle such cases (either with Try, Either, or whatever) in general.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple, performant and functional solution to the problem.
It takes advantage that **Iterators** are *lazy* and `collectFirst` *returns early*.

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def validateAndFind[A, B](data: Seq[A], target: B)
                         (validationFun: A => Either[Throwable, (A, B)]): Try[Option[A]] =
  data
    .iterator
    .map(validationFun)
    .collectFirst {
      case Right((elem, value)) if (value == target) => Right(elem)
      case Left(ex)                                  => Left(ex)
    } match {
      case None              => Success(None)
      case Some(Right(elem)) => Success(Some(elem))
      case Some(Left(ex))    => Failure(ex)
    }
```

However, I am not sure if a **Try** of an **Option** is the best type.
For example, you may just remove the match at the end and return an **Option** of a **Try** instead, or what about just using a custom exception for the value not being found?

```
sealed trait ValidationError extends Product with Serializable
final case object ElementNotFound extends ValidationError
final case class ValidationFailure(cause: Throwable) extends ValidationError

def validateAndFind[A, B](data: Seq[A], target: B)
                         (validationFun: A => Either[Throwable, (A, B)]): Either[ValidationError, A] =
  data
    .iterator
    .map(validationFun)
    .collectFirst {
      case Right((elem, value)) if (value == target) => Right(elem)
      case Left(ex)                                  => Left(ValidationFailure(cause = ex))
    }.getOrElse(Left(ElementNotFound))
```

Anyways, both codes are equivalent and work as expected:

```
final case class User(name: String, age: Int)

validateAndFind(
  data = List(
    User(name = "Balmung", age = 22),
    User(name = "Luis", age = 22),
    User(name = "Miguel", age = 22)
  ),
  target = "Luis"
) { user =>
  println(s"Validating user: ${user}")
  if (user.age < 18) Left(new IllegalArgumentException("User underage"))
  else Right(user -> user.name)
}

// Validating user: User(Balmung,22)
// Validating user: User(Luis,22)
// res: Either[ValidationError, User] = Right(User("Luis", 22))
```

As you can see, it didn't validated the third element, as it wasn't necessary.
Let's see the other two requirements.

```
validateAndFind(
  data = List(
    User(name = "Balmung", age = 16),
    User(name = "Luis", age = 22),
    User(name = "Miguel", age = 22)
  ),
  target = "Luis"
) { user =>
  println(s"Validating user: ${user}")
  if (user.age < 18) Left(new IllegalArgumentException("User underage"))
  else Right(user -> user.name)
}

// Validating user: User(Balmung,16)
// res: Either[ValidationError, User] = Left(ValidationFailure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User underage))
```

And

```
validateAndFind(
  data = List(
    User(name = "Balmung", age = 22),
    User(name = "Luis", age = 22),
    User(name = "Miguel", age = 22)
  ),
  target = "Mario"
) { user =>
  println(s"Validating user: ${user}")
  if (user.age < 18) Left(new IllegalArgumentException("User underage"))
  else Right(user -> user.name)
}

// Validating user: User(Balmung,22)
// Validating user: User(Luis,22)
// Validating user: User(Miguel,22)
// res: Either[ValidationError, User] = Left(ElementNotFound)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
def findUseById(userId: Long, usersJson: Seq[JsObject]): Try[Option[JsObject]] =
  Try(usersJson.find(userJson => (userJson \ "id").validateOpt[Long].map(_ == userId).get)
```

although this violates your first requirement.

Comment: I think `.map(_ == userId)` should be `.map(_.get == userId)`.

Comment: @jrook You are probably right. As I am not sure what library is being used I am making an assumption `validateOpt` returns an `Option` akin to play-json [asOpt](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt)